# How do I stop repeated function calls

Tags: javascript, arrays, ionic2

I am using ionic 2. Here is my root page component.

```
 Backroundnotifications() {
 //Get Current UserID

   var roleid1=localStorage.getItem('Roleid');
   this.authservice.getcurrentuserID().subscribe(
   data => {
       console.log(data);
       this.ApartID=data[0].APART_ID;
       this.USERID=data[0].USER_ID;
       this.EMERGENCY=[];
       if(roleid1 === '2' || roleid1 === '5') {
          this.authservice.GetEmergencytype(this.ApartID).subscribe(d=>{
              var EM=d;
              this.EMERGENCY=EM.filter(a=>a.FROM.toString() != this.USERID.toString());
              console.log("EMERGENCY");
              var emergencyval = this.EMERGENCY.filter(d=>d.STATUS == 'ON');
              console.log("TYPE");
              console.log(emergencyval);
              })
            }
        })
  }

}
```

It seems `Backroundnotifications()` method is getting called again and again. I have logged the value of `emergencyval` on console. This prints out the following.

```
[1,2,3]
[1,2,3]
[1,2,3]
```

How to stop this function getting called repeatedly.

Comment: is it due to event bubbling..? where  u r calling this function..?

Comment: Thanks.I called this function in constructor.